# timer.sleep for loop inputs text into tkinter Text widget all at once instead of iterating

Tags: python, loops, timer, tkinter, sleep

I am writing a function that should put one character every .2 seconds into a tkinter Text widget. 
Unfortunately when I run this function the program hangs for every character all at once and then inserts the entire string instead of iterating normally.

```
def put(win, text):
    #win is a tkinter Text object
    #text is a string of text

    #split text to an array of characters
    output = list(text)

    for i in range(len(output)):
        sleep(0.2)
        win.insert(END, output[i], )
```

EDIT: this does not work either, results are the same

```
def put(win, text):
    #win is a tkinter TExt object
    #text is a string of text

    for char in text:
        win.after(200, win.insert(END, char))
```

EDIT 2: this just hangs

```
def put(win, text):
    #win is a tkinter TExt object
    #text is a string of text

    def place(win, char):
        win.insert(END, char)

    for char in text:
        win.after(200,lambda: put(win, 'z'))
```

Comment: Try to use `after` on `root` not on text object(`win`).

Comment: tried to, it doesnt wait the full increment, it waits the full sum of time for all characters and then puts them all up instantaneously